# Copying .data to RAM

Tags: assembly, memory, linker, system, ram

I was reading a book on Embedded Systems. The author mentions to copy .data section RAM, we need:

```
Address of the data in flash memory (_etext)
Address of the data in RAM ( _data )
Size of the .data section ( _edata to _data )
```

In main assembly code, we need a startup code something like this to copy the .data section to RAM.

```
ResetISR:
ldr r0, =_etext
ldr r1, =_data
ldr r2, =_edata
subs r2, r2, r1
```

This is the linker script:

```
*(.text*)
*(.rodata*)
_etext = .;
} > FLASH

.data : AT(ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
{
    _data = .;
    *(vtable)
    *(.data*)
    _edata = .;
} > SRAM
```

Since _etext has the address of end of .text section in RAM. We need to know the end of .text section in flash memory.
How does the program get to know, the address of end of .text section in flash memory when it is copied to  the RAM?

Comment: Please [**`add tag`**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45396866/edit) of the programming language.

Comment: Added it sir. @VC.One

Comment: `_etext` looks to me as address of end of `.text`, i.e. into flash, not RAM. And to copy the data you don't need end address in flash, the `r0` points into flash where the `.data` are stored in binary (`_etext`), `r1` points into RAM where the `.data` should land after copy (`_data`), and `r2` is length of data `(_edata - _data)`. That's enough information to copy. If you insist on figuring out where the data end in the flash, it's `_etext + r2`, i.e. `_etext + (_edata - _data)`, or in linker script the `ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text) + SIZEOF(.data)` may work.

Comment: Good explanation! But how does it know that _etext should be taken from flash , _data and _etext should be taken from RAM? @Ped7g

Comment: It's been ~10y I have seen any linker script, so I'm just guessing, but the `_etext` is defined inside `.text` block, which ends with `> FLASH`, so that's where it will land. The `.data` block ends with `> SRAM`, but starts with address override `AT(...)`, so it will be stored in binary at that "AT", which points to the end of `.text` block, but the assigned addresses (`_data` and `_edata`) will be from SRAM, like after copy (but that's responsibility of init code to copy it from binary flash area into target SRAM area).

Comment: .text section was copied into FLASH part of the RAM. So I guess `_etext` points to the address in RAM and not in flash or is it the opposite? @Ped7g

Comment: Depends on particular HW and linker script and loading process. The book sounds as it assumes the `_etext` is where the code already resides and runs from, whether that's RAM after loading binary from flash card, or directly some kind of flash memory (EEPROM) - I can't tell from the info you posted. But it is relocating only the `.data` part, so it assumes the `.text` is already where it should be, and that's probably how the `FLASH` is defined in the linker script. Also the HW may have both RAM and SRAM (mapped at different locations).

Comment: `MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 128K
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00030000, LENGTH = 512M
}` This is how it is declared it in the linker script. It is declared according the Goldfish Platform Memory Map

Comment: Now compare that to the HW specs (memory map and chips), so far I'm still not sure how the code lands at 0x10000, if it's the flash memory directly mapped into CPU address space, or the firmware ("OS") loads the binary from flash card into that fixed area of ordinary RAM (probably DRAM). But the lengths look weird to me, usually on embedded boards you have plenty of address space for ROM (EEPROM/other kind of reprogrammable memory), some decent amount of DRAM (if at all), and very little SRAM (as it's most expensive of them), while this suggest only 128K of "flash" and 512M of SRAM.